# Agent Referrer in codeigniter not setting previous url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codigniter here got problem with getting previous url. I have following functions in codeigniter controller.

```
public function contact_us() {
    $this->session->set_userdata('redirect_back', $this->agent->referrer());
    $this->load->view('contact_us');
}

public function find_us() {
    $this->session->set_userdata('redirect_back', $this->agent->referrer());
    $this->load->view('find_us');
}
```

I am getting referrer url in another Login controller like this,

```
public function index(){
    $redirect_url = $this->session->userdata('redirect_back');
    echo $redirect_url;
}
```

I am getting the url but the problem is when

- I go to the **contact_us function** then go to **Login controller** I got
  nothing in **$redirect_url** variable
- if I go to **find_us function** then go to **Login controller** then I get the URL of **contact_us** instead of **find_us** page

I seriously confused or don't understand actuall functionality of user_agent referrer. Kindly provide me the solution or help how get rid of this and sorry if you dont understand my wording. Thanks

Comment: Did you load the user agent library `$this->load->library('user_agent');`

Answer (score 0):

[Codeigniter docs user agent](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html)

> The referrer, if the user agent was referred from another site.

So only works when referred from another site, so it won't work inside your codeigniter application

Comment: completely wrong - it will work just fine in existing domain.